# How to expose a multi-container dockers app with a url in asp.net core

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have built a multi-container dockers app as [described at this url](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/tutorial-multicontainer?view=vs-2019). When I run it from Visual Studio (f5) then the app runs in dockers container and i can open it's url in the browser.

However, I want to access the app's url in the browser without running it in visual studio.

If you can see my dockers desktop screenshot. You can see the container with the app is running. The container keeps on running even if i close visual studio.

[image]

Since the container is running then definately I should access the app with the URL as container is having all the necessary dot net runtime files.

The code of my `docker-compose.yml` file is given below.
version: '3.4'

```
services:
  webfrontendn:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webfrontendn
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: WebFrontEndn/Dockerfile

  mywebapin:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mywebapin
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: MyWebAPIn/Dockerfile
```

I have also added ports on the docker compose but no use:

```
ports:
  - "5000:49226"
```

So how should I do this thing?

Comment: What is the output if your run `docker ps -a` ? take a look at the port for the webfrontendn the ports are written in the format below.

`53803  -> 80`

The port on the left is the **host port**, this is the port you should use when accessing the webfrontendn. It directs traffic to port 80 in the container.

Comment: I get 0.0.0.0:49189->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:49188->443/tcp

Comment: So then you should be able to access the running container on http://localhost:49189 or https://localhost:49188.

Comment: No that is not the point. I can access the url from browser only when running the app from visual studio. When I close the app is not running in visual studio then I am not able to access the url from the browser. Why is this problem ? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by providing a certificate because it will be needed by Kestrel.

These 2 articles helped me to solve the problem.

1. [Hosting ASP.NET Core images with Docker over HTTPS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/docker-https?view=aspnetcore-5.0)
2. [Hosting an ASP.NET Core App on Docker with HTTPS](https://codeburst.io/hosting-an-asp-net-core-app-on-docker-with-https-642cde4f04e8)